# does gcc still support sjlj?

Tags: c++, exception, gcc, clang

The native world moved away from the sjlj exception handling method in favor of the newer table based method due to the zero time cost of the latter when no exception is thrown.

However, I still would like to use the sjlj method. (Due to the really high time cost of the table based method when exception is thrown.)

I know that Visual C++ does not allow me to opt out from the table based method, but I hoped that the free world is more conservative and will keep the old one as an option. Looks like I was wrong, because I can not find options to compile with sjlj not in gcc, nor in clang. Did I miss these options or they really do not support sjlj any more?

Interestingly, gnat, which is based on gcc, [looks to still keep the option](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.4/gnat_ugn_unw/Exception-Handling-Control.html).

Comment: `.../configure --enable-sjlj-exceptions` (not sure how well it will work though)

Answer (score 1):

gcc on Windows uses SJLJ exception handling, while on Linux uses DWARF-2 EH.  Quote from [GCC Wiki](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/WindowsGCCImprovements):

> Platforms like Linux x86-32 have moved to DW2 EH, but Windows is still
>   stuck with SJLJ EH. This is because it is common for Windows
>   developers to write Windows GUI applications where they expect their
>   event loop to catch exceptions thrown within their callback functions.
>   Unfortunately this carries a severe penalty in environments like Java
>   where exceptions are quite common.

However, gcc can be [configured](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html) (as also pointed out by @MarcGlisse) to enable sjlj exceptions.

Comment: But that configuration option is of libstdc++ and not gcc. What if one does not even want to use STL at all. Also, I do not understand how can a library (libstdc++) effect the code generation option of a compiler (gcc).

Comment: Corrected the link above.  The `configure` option mentioned does, indeed, to the main gcc configure script.