# How to compare disassembly of zero cost exceptions with the old approach?

Tags: c++, exception, gcc, x86-64, disassembly

I want to understand how "zero-cost exceptions" differ from the previous approach used to compile exceptions, so I want to look at the assembly code of some program compiled using both, to compare them. How can I do that?

Is there a GCC option I can use to switch between them? Or is there an old version of GCC that uses the old approach (ideally one that's available on Godbolt's Compiler Explorer)? Or something else?

I'm interested in x64 on Linux.

Comment: I found [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20220228-00/?p=106296) that seems to explain quite well the difference. No assembly code though :/

Comment: @Fareanor: As Raymond's article says, normal C++ exceptions *aren't* zero cost.  They also constrain the optimizer somewhat.  I assumed this Q&A was going to be about one of the new proposals for C++ exceptions, like having them work under the hood as special return values.  (Like Herb Sutter's https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0709r4.pdf ).  Also, https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2544r0.html looks at the actual cost when current-style exceptions are taken: a program-wide mutex is taken while unwinding the stack with DWARF metadata.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280143/does-gcc-still-support-sjlj), GCC on linux uses zero-cost exceptions by default but can be configured to use the old ones (SJLJ). It seems you will need to build GCC yourself (and [configure](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html) with `--enable-sjlj-exceptions`)